# Can I use Ubuntu live USB on a MacBook Pro M1?

Tags: live-usb, macbook

You know, like boot into the non-persistent (or sometimes persistent) USB like in a windows computer.

What about the upcoming M1X?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install Ubuntu on a Mac with M1 processor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291377/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-a-mac-with-m1-processor) There is a way to install Ubuntu on it.

Comment: Also keep checking https://asahilinux.org/ for updates.

Answer (score 6):

**No**, sorry.

M1 is a completely different CPU architecture. It's not an amd64 or other supported architecture

It's not a question of "*Linux does not support M1*." It's the other way around: Apple does not support Linux on their proprietary M1 hardware platform. It's Apple's decision, not ours.

See also [How to install Ubuntu on a Mac with M1 processor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291377/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-a-mac-with-m1-processor) for more details and discussion on the hurdles of trying to reverse-engineer a platform that does not encourage such effort.

There is a [project to port Linux to M1](https://asahilinux.org/). However, that project involves reverse-engineering MacOS and M1. It's haywiring Linux onto hardware that the manufacturer *does not provide Linux support for*. A great project for a hobby, but perhaps unwise for reliable daily use.