# Getting a Black screen when dual booting from a MacBook Pro

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, macbook, 21.04

I have successfully installed Ubuntu 21.04 on a partition of my SSD. However since the grub install repeatedly failed whilst installing Ubuntu, I told terminal to install Ubuntu without it. And it did except whenever I select my Ubuntu partition while booting up it immediately gives a black screen. I have tried holding down the left shift button and pressing esc repeatedly and pressing ctrl+alt+T but nothing changes, the screen stays black.

I have also noticed that disk utility back in my Mac OS doesn’t recognize the Ubuntu partition as a OS I don’t know if that’s relevant. But if I try to install Ubuntu again the installer recognizes that Ubuntu is already installed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Comment: @cocomac I don't think that it's a duplicate of the question that is linked to in the previous comment because this problem is probably related to booting Ubuntu on a MacBook.

Comment: @karel I don't know enough about how Linux (or Macs) boot to make a proper answer... but is grub failing to install potentially an issue?

Comment: Yes, grub failing to install is potentially an issue. If the MacBook Pro in this question has an M1 processor please read the discouraging answers at [How to install Ubuntu on a Mac with M1 processor?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1291377/).

Comment: My apologies if I explained myself poorly. Basically I was looking to see if there was any way to get past the black screen without opening the installer again since I’m sure the os was installed in the partition correctly.

Comment: Since that does not seem to be the case I tried reinstalling again with version 20.04 this time. Unfortunately I get the same errors.                           Basically I select a 100 gb partition as my root drive I use the file system ext4 for it. And I select a 9gb partition as SWAP space. But unfortunately the installer says “executing ‘grub-install/dev/nvme0n1p4” failed and then closes the installer and sends me to the trial version of Ubuntu.

Comment: If I try to use Boot-repair in terminal I can successfully run                                                                Sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair.             And sudo apt-get update.    But when I then try sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair    I either get a “couldn’t connect to zsys daemon: connection error .... “ despite having good internet. It the automatically opens boot-repair which no matter what I do gives me the error “/target detected. Please close the Ubuntu installer, then retry.

Comment: I have an intel processor btw not an M1