# Now that Ubuntu 21.10 has Kernel 5.13, will 21.10 Server ARM work on Apple Silicon?

Tags: server, mac, arm, apple, 21.10

I have heard that Ubuntu 21.10 has Kernel 5.13, which supports Apple Silicon, so, does this mean Ubuntu Server 21.10 ARM supports Apple Silicon M1 Macs? And if so, how well?

Comment: @karel that page is from December of 2020, and hence does not take into consideration the Linux Kernel 5.13 present in Ubuntu 21.10.

Comment: @guiverc yeah, I guess I will have to try it out, but where I am in the world has horridly, painfully slow internet, so such a large ISO is quite a big deal to download. So I just wanted to see if anyone has tried it out yet so I could know if my time is just gonna be wasted.

Comment: Why are you using a Q&A site then?  Use a forum (eg. https://ubuntuforums.org/) where opinions are on-topic (they aren't here; this site for is for questions & answers - "how well" requires an off-topic *opinion* (or subjective answer) to be offered.  See https://askubuntu.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @ProfessorConfundus I was referring to Ubuntu 20.10 in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1310778/).

Comment: @guiverc oh, sorry about that, I didn't realise AskUbuntu was for definitive answers only.